# Rate and/or Usage Limits on requesting OAuth2 access tokens from Google?

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

During testing, we have encountered a rate limit error when requesting OAuth2 access tokens too quickly from Google. Our test environment uses the google apps marketplace to grant permissions to a service account.

As far as I know, this rate limit is not publicized. I am wondering:

1. Are the parameters of this rate limit available?
2. Are there any other limits on access token requests, e.g. daily usage limits?